# OSError: [WinError 10049] How do I tackle this error?

Tags: python, sockets, video, camera, stream

I am trying to stream a video feed from a Raspberry Pi to my machine using python. Therefore, I need to connect a socket to the server.
(Streaming video directly at 192.168.0.6:8081 from RPi before executing these)

On my computer I execute this code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import socket


class VideoStreamingTest(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.server_socket = socket.socket()
        self.server_socket.bind(('192.168.0.6', 8081))
        self.server_socket.listen(0)
        self.connection, self.client_address = self.server_socket.accept()
        self.connection = self.connection.makefile('rb')
        self.streaming()

def streaming(self):
    try:
        print ("Connection from: ", self.client_address)
        print ("Streaming...")
        print ("Press 'q' to exit")

        stream_bytes = ' '
        while True:
            stream_bytes += self.connection.read(1024)
            first = stream_bytes.find('\xff\xd8')
            last = stream_bytes.find('\xff\xd9')
            if first != -1 and last != -1:
                jpg = stream_bytes[first:last + 2]
                stream_bytes = stream_bytes[last + 2:]
                #image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
                image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED)
                cv2.imshow('image', image)

                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break
    finally:
        self.connection.close()
        self.server_socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    VideoStreamingTest()
```

During compiling it raises this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/tiger/Desktop/take_the_stream_from_pi.py", line 43, in <module>
    VideoStreamingTest()

File "C:/Users/tiger/Desktop/take_the_stream_from_pi.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.server_socket.bind(('192.168.0.6', 8081))

OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

EDIT: This is also giving

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tiger/Desktop/take_the_stream_from_pi.py", line 47, in 
<module>
    VideoStreamingTest()
  File "C:/Users/tiger/Desktop/take_the_stream_from_pi.py", line 17, in 
__init__
self.connection = self.socket.create_connection(('192.168.0.6', 8081))
AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'create_connection'
```

So I tried to replace create_connection with connect_ex and it still is giving erros.. :(

```
class VideoStreamingTest(object):
    def __init__(self):

    #self.server_socket = socket.socket()
    #self.server_socket.bind(('192.168.0.6', 8081))
    #self.server_socket.listen(0)

    #self.connection, self.client_address = self.server_socket.accept()
    #self.connection = self.connection.makefile('rb')
    #self.streaming()
    self.socket = socket.socket()
    self.connection = self.socket.create_connection(('192.168.0.6', 8081))
    #self.socket.connect(('192.168.0.6', 8081))
    self.streaming()

def streaming(self):

    try:
        #print ("Connection from: ", self.client_address)
        print ("Streaming...")
        print ("Press 'q' to exit")

        stream_bytes = ' '
        while True:
            stream_bytes += self.connection.read(1024)
            first = stream_bytes.find('\xff\xd8')
            last = stream_bytes.find('\xff\xd9')
            if first != -1 and last != -1:
                jpg = stream_bytes[first:last + 2]
                stream_bytes = stream_bytes[last + 2:]
                #image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
                image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED)
                cv2.imshow('image', image)

                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break
    finally:
        self.connection.close()
        self.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    VideoStreamingTest()
```

Comment: `192.168.0.6` is the remote IP address, correct? `socket.bind()` requires an address assigned to your local host.

Comment: ya its IP address of the raspberry pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the IP address in the `bind` command of the socket to the IP address of device which is offering the server, i.e. the address of your own pc. The code you posted here is not going to do what you want to do: it will create a new `server` and will not act as a client which can connect to a server!

This lines

```
self.server_socket.bind(('192.168.0.6', 8081))
self.server_socket.listen(0)
```

have to be replaced with

```
self.socket.connect(('192.168.0.6', 8081))
```

Edit: Maybe it is better to use the `create_connection` function, as it operates on a higher API level. So you will end up with this initialization method:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.socket = socket.socket()
    self.connection, _ = self.socket.create_connection(('192.168.0.6', 8081))
    self.streaming()
```

In the `streaming` method you then have to remove this line, also:

```
print ("Connection from: ", self.client_address)
```

Comment: I will try that right away, I'll let you know if it works! Many thanks!

Comment: @MohdSalman If it helped you, please vote my response up, and mark it as the answer of your question.

Comment: Error:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/tiger/Desktop/take_the_stream_from_pi.py", line 44, in 
    <module>
    VideoStreamingTest()File "C:/Users/tiger/Desktop/take_the_stream_from_pi.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.socket.connect(('192.168.0.6', 8081))
AttributeError: 'VideoStreamingTest' object has no attribute 'socket'

Comment: *I also replaced self.socket.connect.... with self.server_socket.connect... still gave this..*

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tiger/Desktop/take_the_stream_from_pi.py", line 44, in <module>
    VideoStreamingTest()
  File "C:/Users/tiger/Desktop/take_the_stream_from_pi.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.connection, self.client_address = self.server_socket.accept()
  File "C:\Users\tiger\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlowExample\lib\socket.py", line 195, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied

Comment: I am grateful for your help but I am still getting these errors, i did replace create_connection with connect_ex and still got some errors: 
 (I will post errors with connect_ex if u think connect_ex is correct)